# Select jQuery element that does :not have a parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

For this layout

```
<div class="foo">
  <div class="baz"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar">
  <div><div class="baz"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="baz"></div>
```

the selector selects all 3 `.baz` elements:

```
$(':not(.foo, .bar) .baz');
```

I would expect it to select only `.baz` that doesn't have `.foo` or `.bar` parent.

What's wrong with it and how can it be fixed?

I suppose that the selector is not efficient, but it's efficiency is not a priority. How can it be rewritten to be more efficient?

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this would be to select by the parent of these elements as CSS cannot go up the DOM tree. Something like `#container > .baz`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's for sure. The problem is that third `baz` doesn't have a specific parent it could be selected with.

Comment: @estus he means to enclose those div in a single parent with id container and use the selector `#container > .baz` to select child div with baz class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `:not` solution doesn't work because it matches all `.baz` elements, since `html`, `body`, and probably others are `:not(.foo, .bar)` but *are* ancestors of all your `.baz` elements.

Instead:

```
$(".baz").not(".bar .baz").not(".foo .baz")
```

Example:

```js
console.log($(".baz").not(".bar .baz").not(".foo .baz").length);
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="baz"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar">
  <div>
    <div class="baz"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="baz"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```